# Cannot add edges, Invalid vertex ID in IGraph

Tags: python, igraph

I was trying to write the code in python using igraph and when i tried to add edges using a while loop this error came up

```
while(i<k)
  g.add_vertices(theInts[i])
  i=i+1
  g.add_edges([(theInts[i-1],theInts[i])])
```

I thought that indexing might be a problem so i also included a if statement but that doesnt seems to be the problem.

Please Help!!!

Comment: What are the values of `i` and `k` before entering the loop ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this all depends on what `g` has for vertices.  If you start off with an empty `g`, you only have the vertex `0`, so if you're trying to call `add_edges` with two different vertices, it's just not going to work.  You have to add some more vertices.  Of course this all depends on what your graph looks like before the loop, and what `i` is.

You can display some brief information about your graph with `print`.  For example,

```
>>> import igraph
>>> graph = igraph.Graph()
>>> print graph
Undirected graph (|V| = 1, |E| = 0)
```

If `i` starts at 0, then you will not add any vertices with your loop the first time around.  So when you try to add edges, you're trying to add to vertices that do not exist.

```
>>> graph.add_vertices(0)
<igraph.Graph object at 0xcea850>
>>> print graph
Undirected graph (|V| = 1, |E| = 0)
>>> graph.add_edges([(0, 1)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
igraph.core.InternalError: Error at type_indexededgelist.c:245: cannot add edges, Invalid vertex id
```

If that is not the issue, try printing the edges and see if they match up with what you want.

```
>>> graph.add_vertices(5)
<igraph.Graph object at 0xcea850>
>>> print graph
Undirected graph (|V| = 6, |E| = 3)
>>> graph.add_edges([(1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 5)])
<igraph.Graph object at 0xcea850>
>>> graph.get_edgelist()
[(1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 5)]
```

Also, it might be a bit more helpful to have the complete TraceBack.

EDIT: Based on your comment

So you're saying you have a structure like this:

```
>>> graph = igraph.Graph()
>>> print graph
Undirected graph (|V| = 1, |E| = 0)
```

And you want to add just vertex 2?  I am not sure that you can do that with igraph.  It seems to have to have each vertex in order.  You can check to see if you have the vertex and then add them if necessary, remembering that these graphs are 0-based.  Something like this.

```
>>> vertices = 1, 2, 13, 4, 21, 5
>>> map_graph = igraph.Graph()
>>> print map_graph
Undirected graph (|V| = 1, |E| = 0)
>>> map_graph.add_vertices(max(vertices))
<igraph.Graph object at 0xceaa50>
>>> print map_graph
Undirected graph (|V| = 22, |E| = 0)
>>> map(map_graph.add_edges, zip(vertices, vertices[1:]))
[<igraph.Graph object at 0xceaa50>, <igraph.Graph object at 0xceaa50>, <igraph.Graph object at 0xceaa50>, <igraph.Graph object at 0xceaa50>, <igraph.Graph object at 0xceaa50>]
>>> print map_graph
Undirected graph (|V| = 22, |E| = 5)
>>> map_graph.get_edgelist()
[(1, 2), (2, 13), (4, 13), (4, 21), (5, 21)]
```

Or if you don't like maps, you can loop it up.

```
>>> vertices = 1, 2, 13, 4, 21, 5
>>> loop_graph = igraph.Graph()
>>> print loop_graph
Undirected graph (|V| = 1, |E| = 0)
>>> loop_graph.add_vertices(max(vertices))
<igraph.Graph object at 0xcea950>
>>> print loop_graph
Undirected graph (|V| = 22, |E| = 0)
>>> for pair in zip(vertices, vertices[1:]):
...     loop_graph.add_edges(pair)
... 
<igraph.Graph object at 0xcea950>
<igraph.Graph object at 0xcea950>
<igraph.Graph object at 0xcea950>
<igraph.Graph object at 0xcea950>
<igraph.Graph object at 0xcea950>
>>> print loop_graph
Undirected graph (|V| = 22, |E| = 5)
>>> loop_graph.get_edgelist()
[(1, 2), (2, 13), (4, 13), (4, 21), (5, 21)]
```

There is probably a better way to do this though.  If this isn't what you're looking for, please edit your original question with more detail, and some actual code.

Comment: actually i m doing g.add_vertices(vertice[i]) which is not giving me the correct result as when the value of vertice[i]=2 then it is adding 2 vertices but what i want is to add a vertice of name 2. Please help on this one!

Comment: @Fyre, I'm not sure if my edit answers your question.  Perhaps you could provide more detail in your original question if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks confab for your reply. But what i am actually saying that is it possible to add a vertice named 21? In this case when you added 21 it added 21 to the previous number of vertices but what i want to do is make 21 as a vertice and total number of vertices as only 2.

Comment: igraph identifies the vertices by numbers from zero to N-1, where N is the number of vertices. Names can be attached to the vertices as vertex attributes after you have added them; e.g., you could say `graph.vs[2]["name"] = "spam"` to assign the name `"spam"` to the vertex with id=2. Or you could say: `graph.add_vertices(1); graph.vs[0]["name"] = "21"` to add a single vertex to an empty graph and then name it `21`, but you will have to refer to it with its id later on, and not by its name (unless you maintain a dictionary that maps vertex names back to ids).

Comment: Is there any way that i can find out which edge contains which vertice like i m trying to detect cycles in my graph and i want to see if that particular edge contains 2 given vertices so i can colour them out and show them differently.Thanks