# igraph invalid vertex Id

Tags: python-2.7, cluster-analysis, igraph, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to run igraph's fast greedy community detection algorithm using the following code:

```
G = Graph()

L = []
V = []
for row in cr:

    try:
        l = []
        source = int((row[0]).strip())
        target = int((row[1]).strip())
        weight = int((row[2]).strip())
        l.append(source)
        l.append(target)

        if l not in L:
            L.append(l)

        if source not in V:
            V.append(source)

        if target not in V:
            V.append(target)
    except ValueError:
        print "Value Error"
        continue

    if weight == 1:
        continue

G.add_vertices(max(V))
G.add_edges(L)
cl = G.community_fastgreedy(weights=weight).as_clustering(10);
```

But this is the error I'm getting:
    igraph._igraph.InternalError: Error at type_indexededgelist.c:272: cannot add edges, Invalid vertex id

I found this: [Cannot add edges, Invalid vertex ID in IGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055246/cannot-add-edges-invalid-vertex-id-in-igraph) so I tried adding all the vertices and then all the edges but I still get an error.

Does the above code do the same thing as:

```
tupleMapping = []
for row in cr:
    if int(row[2]) < 10:
        continue

    l = [row[0], row[1], row[2]]
    tupleMapping.append(tuple(l))

g = Graph.TupleList(tupleMapping)
cl = g.community_fastgreedy().as_clustering(20)
```

I dont have to explicitly say the G.community_fastgreedy(weights=weight) right?

Also another problem I was having; when I try to add more clusters in the following way:

```
cl = g.community_fastgreedy().as_clustering(10)
cl = g.community_fastgreedy().as_clustering(20)
```

I get two large clusters and the rest of the clusters compose of one element. This happens when I try to make the cluster size 5/10/20, is there any way for me to make the clusters more equally divided? I need more than 2 clusters for my dataset.

This is a small snippet of the data I'm trying to read from the csv file so that I can generate a graph and then run the community detection algorithm:
    202,580,11
    87,153,7
    227,459,6
    263,524,11

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right, the second code does the same. In the first example, the problem is that when you add edges, you refer to igraph's internal vertex IDs, which always start from 0, and go until `N-1`. Does not matter your own vertex names are integers, you need to translate them to igraph vertex IDs.

The `igraph.Graph.TupleList()` method is much more convenient here. However, you need to specify that the third element of the tuple is the weight. You can do it either by `weights = True` or `edge_attrs = ['weight']` arguments:

```
import igraph

data = '''1;2;34
1;3;41
1;4;87
2;4;12
4;5;22
5;6;33'''

L = set([])

for row in data.split('\n'):
    row = row.split(';')
    L.add(
        (row[0].strip(), row[1].strip(), int(row[2].strip()))
    )

G = igraph.Graph.TupleList(L, edge_attrs = ['weight'])
```

You can then create dictionaries to translate between igraph vertex IDs and your original names:

```
vid2name = dict(zip(xrange(G.vcount()), G.vs['name']))
name2vid = dict((name, vid) for vid, name in vid2name.iteritems())
```

However, the first is not so much needed, as you can always use `G.vs[vid]['name']`.

For fastgreedy, I think you should specify the weights, at least the documentation does not tell if it automatically considers the attribute named `weight` if such attribute exists.

```
fg = G.community_fastgreedy(weights = 'weight')
fg_clust_10 = fg.as_clustering(10)
fg_clust_20 = fg.as_clustering(20)
```

If fastgreedy gives you only 2 large clusters, I can only recommend to try other community detection methods. Actually you could try all of them which run within reasonable time (it depends on the size of your graph), and then compare their results. Also because you have a weighted graph, you could take a look at [moduland method family](http://www.linkgroup.hu/modules.php), which is not implemented in igraph, but has good documentation, and you can set quite sophisticated settings.

**Edit:** The comments from OP suggest that the original data describes a directed graph. The fastgreedy algorithm is unable to consider directions, and gives error if called on a directed graph. That's why in my example I created an undirected `igraph.Graph()` object. If you want to run other methods, some of those might able to deal with directed networks, you should create first a directed graph:

```
G = igraph.Graph.TupleList(L, directed = True, edge_attrs = ['weight'])
G.is_directed()
# returns True
```

To run fastgreedy, convert the graph to undirected. As you have a weight attribute for the edges, you need to specify what igraph should do when 2 edges of opposit direction between the same pair of vertices being collapsed to one undirected edge. You can do many things with the weights, like taking the mean, the larger, or the smaller one, etc. For example, to make the combined edges have a mean weight of the original edges:

```
uG = G.as_undirected(combine_edges = 'mean')
fg = uG.community_fastgreedy(weights = 'weight')
```

Important: be aware that at this operation, and also when you add or remove vertices or edges, igraph reindexes the vertices and edges, so if you know that vertex id `x` corresponds to your original  id `y`, after reindexing this won't be valid anymore, you need to recreate the `name2vid` and `vid2name` dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks that's great! Now I get 2 large clusters, 2 medium sized clusters and  the rest of the clusters have single elements. I didnt realise you had to specify a weight but it definitely made a difference to the results. The graph is directed but I dont know how to incorporate that. I see from the documentation that you add directed = 'true' but there but be something that you do in an earlier step which specifies the direction. Could you give an example of how to make this code work for a directed graph? or I could ask on a different question.

Comment: I found out fastgreedy only works with undirected graphs. Do you have any suggestions on how to deal with a directed graph? Thanks.

Comment: You can still use fastgreedy, but it does not consider directionality, so you loose that additional information. Once you initialize the `igraph.Graph()` object, you decide if it will be a directed or undirected network. Here we initialized it to be undirected, exactly because fastgreedy needs an undirected graph. If you use other methods, like spinglass, which are able to consider directions, you should create a directed network: `igraph.Graph.TupleList(L, directed = True, ...)`. You can also convert between directed and undirected graphs with `as_directed()` and `as_undirected()` methods.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. When you get the same result if you fastgeedy a directed graph or an undirected graph?

Comment: If just a little unclear, on one thing, if I just directed=true does that generate an arrow from source -> target? is that always the case? if it's bidirectional do i need to have two entries? 1 -> 2 and 2 -> 1 (vertices 1 and 2)

Comment: So if you take the mean of the edges what effect does that have on the graph?

Comment: Sorry some of these questions are so basic but I am really sick and i'm finding it difficult to find the answers online so I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: You can not run fastgreedy on undirected graph, igraph simply throws an error if you try.

Comment: If you build a graph with `directed = True`, then you can add 1 -> 2 and/or 2 -> 1 edge separately. If you build an undirected graph, it does not matter if you add 1 -> 2 or 2 -> 1, the two endpoints are equal, and it is only matter of chance which will be the "source" or "target", because undirected edges don't have source and target, just 2 endpoints, it is really random. You should not assume in case of undirected graph that source will be 1 if you added the edge 1 -> 2, because it can be 2 with equal chance. That's why it is undirected.

Comment: It depends on your data if it makes sense to take the average/minimum/maximum weight of 2 edges of the opposite directections, and then run fastgreedy. I can imagine it does not make sense at all, and then you should not use fastgreedy, but only other methods.